# Are there downsides to using pointer-events: none over display: none with fade animations?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Often fade in/out animations seem to be trickier then they should be because you also have to time display:none to toggle at the right moments.

Is there a downside to toggling pointer-events: none instead of display: none?

Assume the element is absolutely positioned, so we're not worrying about it taking up space.

Example code showing a fade animation using pointer-events instead of display: none.

```js
function animate(e) {
  document.body.querySelector('p').className = 'animate'
}
```

```css
p {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

p.animate {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: unset;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='window.animate()'>Clicky!</button>
<p>Hi there</p>
```

Comment: so, what is the question?

Comment: @smnbbrv I guess I didn't explain the meat of the question very well :p. The example provided is using a combination of pointer-events and opacity to simulate the functionality of display none. Its being done in this format to make the fade animation easier to code, but I'm wondering if there's stuff display: none does in addition that I should know about that might make this approach less attractive.

Comment: Well you can't transition `display` anyway so I'm also not clear on what it is you are asking or why pointer-events is relevant.

Comment: @paulie_d No you can't, which is why fade transitions are normally difficult to do. If, for example I want to fade something out, I would normally transition the opacity, attach a transitionend listener to the element, and once its fully transitioned out I would flip the display property to be none. You can't transition pointer-events either, but with pointer-events it really doesn't matter weather pointer-events is set or not during the transition, as long as its set correctly when the animation is over. display is more picky, you can't have it set to none during an animation.

Comment: You can imagine in the code snippet provided above that I was fading another button in and out. The pointer-events is being used so that you can't interact with it after it's faded out. But the essence of the question is if there's a problem to such an approach that I might be unaware about over display none. (e.g. maybe screen readers would work incorrectly or something, I don't know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already hinted, the downside, compared to `display: none;`, is that only pointer-events are disabled. The element is still there in rendered output and selectable, be it may with something else than a pointer.

`pointer-events: none;` won't prevent from focusing an element using the `TAB` key, for instance.

For all non-interactive elements such as overlay-screens etc. it shouldn't be an issue. But for any element with which can be or should be interacted, I wouldn't use `pointer-events` to control whether the element is interactive, as it simply only covers one use-case: that of a pointer.

I tend to opt for adding a listener for `animationend` or `transitionend` to animate something with CSS and after the animation setting the `display` to `none`:

```
function animate(_e) {
  _e.currentTarget.passEffectOn.classList.add('animate');
}

function animationEnd(_e) {
  _e.target.style.display = 'none';
  _e.target.passOn.classList.add('animate');
}

const myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
const myParagraph = document.getElementById('myParagraph');
const theirParagraph = document.getElementById('theirParagraph');

myButton.passEffectOn = myParagraph;
myParagraph.passOn = theirParagraph;

myButton.addEventListener('click', animate);
myButton.passEffectOn.addEventListener('transitionend', animationEnd);
```

```
#myParagraph {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

#myParagraph.animate {
  opacity: 0;
}

#theirParagraph {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}

#theirParagraph.animate {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```
<button id="myButton">Clicky!</button>

<p id="myParagraph">Hi there</p>

<p id="theirParagraph">The other is <code>display: none;</code></p>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aptoptout/dr9cx4Lk/13/)